# Fast SQL question about multiple month dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, reporting-services, data-access

```
SELECT DISTINCT MonthName(Month([Date])) AS [Month], tblSupportCalls.System, Count(tblSupportCalls.System) AS [Total for System], Year([Date]) AS [Year]
FROM tblSupportCalls
WHERE (((tblSupportCalls.Date) Between Now() And Now()-7) AND ((tblSupportCalls.System) In ('Career Campus','E-PEEP')) AND ((tblSupportCalls.StartTime) Is Not Null) AND ((Hour([StartTime]))>=7))
GROUP BY tblSupportCalls.System, tblSupportCalls.Date;
```

Whenever I input that it gives me multiple months like:

```
July
July
July
```

I want it just to say July just 1 time and I cant figure out why ever field is repeating itself for different days. I just want it to say:

MONTH | System | Total Systems | Year

what I am looking at is

```
> MONTH | System | Total Systems | Year
> July      CC           2         2010
> July      CC           7         2010
> July      CC           9         2010
> July      EE           1         2010
> July      EE           2         2010
```

Needs to be:

```
MONTH | System | Total Systems | Year
July      CC          18         2010
July      EE          03         2010
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to group by your Year and Month instead of `tblSupportCalls.Date`.

```
...
GROUP BY tblSupportCalls.System, Year([Date]), Month([Date]);
```

Comment: can you post a example of what you are talking about joe. I have tried that but i may have typed it in wrong

Comment: @Alex: I've added the group by clause to my answer.

Comment: needs to group by 3 fields. Also, monthname is not needed in the group by, it can be done in the select against the grouped `month(date)`

Comment: @Richard: I caught the Year. Modified month as suggested. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You're still grouping the results by date, though (not by month). I think what you want is something like this:

```
GROUP BY tblSupportCalls.System, Year ([tblSupportCalls.Date]), [Month([tblSupportCalls.Date]);
```

I'm thinking you still want to group by Year as well, so that July 2010 shows up in a different row from July 2011.